# Want to Hide File Downloading Popup Through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA macro for collecting data from sharedrive. When we open any Excel spreadsheet from share drive via macro, it shows the "downloading" pop up box which has a progress bar in it.

I am looking for code to hide that downloading popup. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Comment: Please help me how can I hide Excel file openingg popup through VBA

Comment: Please include your VBA code snippet in the question, so we will be able to look into it and possibly help with a solution. Kind regards,

Comment: Please clarify: Are you working on one (1) or more (2, 3...) workbooks? Are you seeing the popup when opening (1) or when opening (2) or (3) from within (1)? In case of the second scenario, `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `= True` might help, in the first there's little you can do since you can't run a macro that you haven't opened / downloaded first.

Answer (score 1):

It's been almost a year since you posted your question, and it was a very specific one, so I understand if you are not interested any longer. However, I just had the same issue downloading public databases from the Central Bank of Chile and I believe that I found an acceptable solution.

First, `the Application.DisplayAlerts = False` will not help you. It only hides Excel's prompts, but you were asking about an VBA's prompt, right?.

Use instead `Application.SendKeys "~", True` before opening an url. What it does is to hit the Enter key which closes the 'Downloading prompt' as soon as opened.

I really don't know what this prompt is for. Cancelling it does not stop the download process and does not cut nor corrupt the file.

SendKeys commands resulted very usefull to me. I hope they could help you too.

Regards,

F